# What is the best Google Analytics tool for use with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I've developed a RoR application, and want to integrate Google Analytics so I can track usage etc... what is options I have, and which is the best choice? I'm not looking for anything too complicated, the easier it is to integrate the better. I'm only really after fairly basic functions.

Bernard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be for you to include the google analytics code in your application's layout file(s)'s footer.

You could find a plugin to do the same, but it's simple enough to not warrant a plugin in my opinion.

Something like the following in your layout files.

```
<%= render("shared/google_analytics") %>
```

In app/views/shared/_google_analytics.html.erb

```
<%= GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE %>
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya, I tried doing this but when I simply add the js that google tells me to do within the _google_analytics.html.erb form I get the following error.

Comment: /Users/bernardleung/Documents/My Development/mywedding/app/views/shared/_google_analytics.html.erb:12: unterminated string meets end of file) on line #2 of app/views/shared/_google_analytics.html.erb:
1: <%= 
2:  <script type="text/javascript">
3:     var _gaq = _gaq || [];
4:     _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-20628327-1"]);
5:     _gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);

Comment: <%= 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-20628327-1"]);
    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement("script"); ga.type = "text/javascript"; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
     })();
 </script>
%>

Comment: ah you're doing it wrong! just page the google analytics code without the "<%=" and "%>" since you dont have any string interpolation.

Comment: i must add, that I WAS responsible for the wrong hint. <%= should not have been there %>

Comment: Thanks Aditya. It seems to complile and run now however I'm confused as it won't display anything on google analytics. I can see that the script gets called each time "Rendered shared/_google_analytics (0.1ms)", but nothing is being displayed in Analytics! Any suggestions on how to debug this?? The JS code is the exact JS code I am told to put by Google Analytics, so I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: Reporting in google analytics is not immediate. Clicks are collected and reported in GA after a short while. Check after a day.

Comment: Hi Aditya, yep that was the issue! All working now, thanks for your excellent help!

Comment: do analytics also record traffic/activity in your development and test environments? you should probably do a check on the partial to make sure it's only loaded in production.

Answer (score 1):

I've been very pleased with [Gattica](https://github.com/activenetwork/gattica)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [rack-google-analytics](https://github.com/ambethia/rack-google_analytics) can help you.